# Show that a function $F$ is continuous using a bound

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, continuity, alternative-proof

This is a continuation of [this exercise](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029254/in-search-of-easier-manipulation-of-an-inequality-to-prove-it).

> Let the zigzag function defined as
>
> $$zz(x):=\left|\lfloor x+1/2\rfloor-x\right|,\quad x\in\Bbb R$$
>
> Then for $k\in\Bbb Z$ we have that $zz(k)=0$, and $zz(\Bbb R)=[0,1/2]$, and $zz$ is increasing in any interval of the kind $[k,k+1/2]$, and decreasing in $[k+1/2,k+1]$ for $k\in\Bbb Z$.
>
> Then we define the function
>
> $$F(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{zz(4^nx)}{4^n},\quad x\in\Bbb R$$

Now I must prove that $F$ is continuous only using the fact that

$$|F(x)-F(y)|\le \frac1{4^m3}+\sum_{n=0}^m |f_n(x)-f_n(y)|\tag{1}$$

where $f_n(x)=4^{-n}zz(4^nx)$.

**The book have not stated any theorem about uniform convergence so it cannot be used here, at least not directly.**

---

#### Proof

I will show that $zz$ is Lipschitz continuous. It is enough to consider $x,y\in[0,1]$ because the function $zz$ is cyclic with period $1$.

First observe that if $x\in [0,1/2)$ then $zz(x)=x$, then for $x,y\in[0,1/2)$ the function $zz$ is Lipschitz continuous with $K=1$. If $x\in[1/2,1]$ then $zz(x)=1-x$, so if $x,y\in[1/2,1]$, so $zz$ is again Lipschitz continuous with $K=1$.

Then we need to confirm that if $x\in[0,1/2)$ and $y\in[1/2,1]$ then $zz$ is Lipschitz. Then it is enough to observe that

$$|zz(x)-zz(y)|=|x+y-1|\le|x-y|=\begin{cases}x+y-1\le y-x\implies x\le 1/2\\1-x-y\le y-x\implies y\ge 1/2\end{cases}$$

because both cases are true then $zz$ is Lipschitz, with $K=1$. Then choosing enough big $m$ such that $\frac1{4^m3}<\frac{\epsilon}2$ and choosing $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2(m+1)}$ we have that

$$|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|=4^{-n}|zz(4^nx)-zz(4^ny)|\le 4^{-n}|4^nx-4^ny|<\frac{\epsilon}{2(m+1)}$$ we finally have that

$$|x-y|<\delta\implies |F(x)-F(y)|\le \frac1{4^m3}+\sum_{n=0}^m|f_n(x)-f_n(y)|<(m+1)\frac{\epsilon}{2(m+1)}+\frac{\epsilon}2=\epsilon$$

so $F$ is continuous.$\Box$

---

Questions:

1. It is the proof correct? (It seems that it is correct but a confirmation will be welcome).
2. There is a easier way to prove this in the context of this exercise (i.e. not using theorems about uniform convergence)?

Comment: Start with "Choose $m$ so large that $\frac{1}{4^m3} < \varepsilon/2$". Can you see how to continue after that?

Comment: @DanielFischer I have written a proof but Im not sure if you pointed to this direction.

Comment: It's not exactly what I had in mind, but very close. Every $f_n$ is continuous (since $zz$ is continuous), so, given $y\in \mathbb{R}$ and $\varepsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta_n > 0$ such that $\lvert x-y\rvert < \delta_n \implies \lvert f_n(x) - f_n(y)\rvert < \frac{\varepsilon}{2(m+1)}$. Then let $\delta = \min \{ \delta_n : 0 \leqslant n \leqslant m\}$. By showing that $f_n$ has Lipschitz constant $1$ for all $n$, you immediately get a $\delta$ that works for all $n$ at once and is independent of $y$.

Comment: Your proof is essentially correct, but there are one-and-a-half issues establishing that $zz$ is Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant $1$. Formally, your $$|zz(x)-zz(y)|=|x+y-1|\le|x-y|=\begin{cases}x+y-1\le y-x\implies x\le 1/2\\1-x-y\le y-x\implies y\ge1/2\end{cases}$$ doesn't make sense, though it's clear what you mean. Strictly, you need to start at the other end, $$\left.\begin{array}{} x \leqslant 1/2\implies x+y-1\leqslant y-x\\y\geqslant1/2\implies1-x-y\leqslant y-x\end{array}\right\}\implies y-x\geqslant\lvert x+y-1\rvert=\lvert zz(y)-zz(x)\rvert$$

Comment: for $0\leqslant x\leqslant 1/2\leqslant y \leqslant 1$. That you write $\implies x \le 1/2$ and $\implies y \ge 1/2$ is actually wrong, you don't want to conclude these inequalities from $x+y-1 \le y-x$ etc., but the other way round. Then there is a half-issue with your argument for only looking at $x,y \in [0,1]$. You don't give an argument why you needn't look at e.g. $x \in [-1/2,0]$ and $y\in [0,1/2]$ too. That's obvious when you look at the graph, but "obvious" is not a proof, some words about that might not be misplaced.

Comment: Of course, if you can use it, it's enough to note that $zz$ is (continuous and) piecewise continuously differentiable, with the derivative being constant $\pm 1$ on each interval, whence $$\lvert zz(y) - zz(x)\rvert \leqslant \int_x^y \lvert zz'(t)\rvert\,dt = y-x.$$